# Django - Q Object much slower than doing separate queries

Tags: sql, django, database, indexing

I have the following model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True)
    alternative_address = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True)
```

---

I'm querying for a particular address, which can either match `full_address` or `alternative_address`.  The obvious solution is to use a Q object.  But for some reason, using a Q object makes the query much slower.

```
address = '123 Main Street'

# This query using Q object takes 500ms (10x slower)
addresses = Address.objects.filter(Q(full_address__startswith=address) | Q(alternative_address__startswith=address)).values(...)

# This solution, which returns the same results, takes just 50ms
addresses1 = Address.objects.filter(full_address__startswith=address).values(...)
addresses2 = Address.objects.filter(alternative_address__startswith=address).values(...)
addresses = addresses1 | addresses2
```

---

Is this supposed to happen?  I think using a Q object in this case should be faster, not slower, right?

---

EDIT: Raw SQL queries added

Fast query.  Took about 0.002 seconds for both `full_address` and `alternative_address`

```
SELECT 
  "testapp_address"."street",
  "testapp_address"."city",
  "testapp_address"."la",
  "testapp_address"."lo",
  "testapp_address"."id" 
FROM "testapp_address" 
WHERE "testapp_address"."full_address"::text LIKE \'1 Bloor St%\' 
LIMIT 21
```

Q Object query.  Took 0.449 seconds.

```
SELECT
  "testapp_address"."street",
  "testapp_address"."city",
  "testapp_address"."la",
  "testapp_address"."lo",
  "testapp_address"."id"
FROM "testapp_address"
WHERE (
  "testapp_address"."full_address"::text LIKE \'1 Bloor St%\'
  OR "testapp_address"."alternative_address"::text LIKE \'1 Bloor St%\'
)
LIMIT 21
```

Comment: Have you looked at what SQL is generated by both queries? You can execute your queries in Django shell and look up the SQL that was executed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 I just did.  Added my analysis to the question.  Running the queries separately is super fast.  But when you combine the two queries with `OR`, it slows down dramatically.

Comment: My hypothesis is that there's no multi-column index for full and alt addresses. Could you please share what `EXPLAIN SELECT ... LIMIT 21;` says for both queries? Meanwhile I'm going to add some sql-ish tags - it seems to be a database issue.